# Is there a homology theory for graphs which counts complete graph minors?

Tags: graph-theory, homology-cohomology, algebraic-graph-theory

I have a strong feeling that complete graph minors ($K^i$ minors) are like a sort of cycles in a simplicial complex. Is there a homology theory (for graphs) counting complete graph minors?